# How do I set a number of rows and count the conditional results?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to count the number of conditions from a set number of 100 results.

Example: Of the last set 100 actions, how many were for 'X'?

I'm not quite sure where to start.

I'm fairly new to SQL, and I've tried inner joins, subqueries, etc, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I feel it's something fairly simple.

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you simply need to `sum` up a `case` statement that checks for the value. However, if you want to do this for only 100 rows, you will need to perform this query against a `derived table` (or a Common Table Expression, if your RDBMS supports it) to do that row count restriction.

Here is an example that should work in most RDBMSes (you may need to replace `TOP` with `LIMIT`, depending on your RDBMS):

```
select
    sum(
        case 
            when (my_val='X') then 
                1
            else 
                0 
        end
    )
from
    (
        select top 100 
            my_val
        from
            my_table
    ) t
```

Comment: In Snowflake. you can also simplify it with `IFF(my_val = 'X', 1, 0)`

Comment: @MarcinZukowski You should consider providing an answer that is specific to Snowflake. I don't have any experience with it, so I don't feel comfortable adding that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

@RToyo's answer covers it for any DBMS.

In Snowflake you can slightly simplify it by using [`IFF`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/iff.html):

```
select
    sum(IFF(my_val='X', 1, 0))
from
    (
        select top 100 
            my_val
        from
            my_table
    ) t
```