# Replicating FILTER clause from Postgres in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, conditional-aggregation

Postgres have a really useful method called `FILTER` which doesn't seem to be in Snowflake. In Postgres it works like this:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  MIN(orders.started_at) FILTER (WHERE orders.sequence_in_subscription = 1) as time_of_t1
FROM platform.orders
GROUP BY 1
```

How would you do this in Snowflake? Is there such a concise way to do this?

Might be quite a basic question, but I'm fairly new to the Snowflake world and have only really done Postgres before. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: There is also IFF, a shorter way of writing case statement.  See this other question with an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55716546/1335793

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you may use a `CASE` expression in place of the `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    MIN(CASE WHEN orders.sequence_in_subscription = 1 THEN orders.started_at END) AS time_of_t1
FROM platform.orders
GROUP BY
    user_id;
```

Comment: OK, great thanks! I thought there might be a more concise way but this will work. Thanks for the help